# Convert a List of Map in Java to Dataset in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a list of Map in java, essentially representing rows.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> row1 = new HashMap<>();
row1.put("fund", "f1");
row1.put("broker", "b1");
row1.put("qty", 100);

Map<String, Object> row2 = new HashMap<>();
row2.put("fund", "f2");
row2.put("broker", "b2");
row2.put("qty", 200);

dataList.add(row1);
dataList.add(row2);
```

I'm trying to create a Spark DataFrame from it.

I've tried to convert it into `JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>>` using

```
JavaRDD<Map<String,Object>> rows = sc.parallelize(dataList);
```

But I'm not sure how to go from here to `Dataset<Row>`. I've seen Scala examples but none in Java.

I also tried to convert the list to JSON string, and read the JSON string.

```
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataList);
```

But seems like I will have to write it to a file to then read using

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(pathToFile);
```

I would prefer to do it in-memory if possible rather than write to file and read from there.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("local[*]")
            .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    SparkSession sparkSession = 
SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> row1 = new HashMap<>();
row1.put("fund", "f1");
row1.put("broker", "b1");
row1.put("qty", 100);

Map<String, Object> row2 = new HashMap<>();
row2.put("fund", "f2");
row2.put("broker", "b2");
row2.put("qty", 200);

dataList.add(row1);
dataList.add(row2);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataList);
JavaRDD<Map<String,Object>> rows = sc.parallelize(dataList);
Dataset<Row> data = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, Map.class);
data.show();
```

Comment: dataframe/dataset is a columnar structure. what is the value of column (or columns) that you want your map row to be associated with? and by the way, have you tried "createDataFrame(rows, Map.class)"? what was the result?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use RDDs at all. What you need to do is extract the desired schema from your list of maps, transform you list of maps into a list of rows and then use `spark.createDataFrame`.

In java, that's a bit painful, particularly when creating the `Row` objects, but here is how it could go:

```java
List<String> cols = new ArrayList(dataList.get(0).keySet());
List<Row> rows = dataList
    .stream()
    .map(row -> cols.stream().map(c -> (Object) row.get(c).toString()))
    .map(row -> row.collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .map(row -> JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(row).asScala().toSeq())
    .map(Row$.MODULE$::fromSeq)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

StructType schema = new StructType(
    cols.stream()
        .map(c -> new StructField(c, DataTypes.StringType, true, new Metadata()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new StructField[0])
);
Dataset<Row> result = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyRow implements Serializable {

  private String fund;
  private String broker;
  private int qty;

  public MyRow(String fund, String broker, int qty) {
    super();
    this.fund = fund;
    this.broker = broker;
    this.qty = qty;
  }

  public String getFund() {
    return fund;
  }

  public void setFund(String fund) {
    this.fund = fund;
  }


  public String getBroker() {
    return broker;
  }

  public void setBroker(String broker) {
    this.broker = broker;
  }

  public int getQty() {
    return qty;
  }

  public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
  }

}
```

Now create an ArrayList. Each item in this list will act as row in final dataframe.

```
MyRow r1 = new MyRow("f1", "b1", 100);
MyRow r2 = new MyRow("f2", "b2", 200);
List<MyRow> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(r1);
dataList.add(r2);
```

Now We have to convert this List into a DataSet -

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.createDataFrame(dataList, MyRow.class);
ds.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure of MyRow changes dynamically, so I need to be able to do this dynamically.

Comment: @gargravarr. I also have dynamic schema how have you resolve it?

Comment: @gargravarr could anybody do that for dynamic schema ?

Answer (score 0):

The spark document had already point out how to load in-memory json string.

Here is the example from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

```java
// Alternatively, a DataFrame can be created for a JSON dataset represented by
// a Dataset<String> storing one JSON object per string.
List<String> jsonData = Arrays.asList(
        "{\"name\":\"Yin\",\"address\":{\"city\":\"Columbus\",\"state\":\"Ohio\"}}");
Dataset<String> anotherPeopleDataset = spark.createDataset(jsonData, Encoders.STRING());
Dataset<Row> anotherPeople = spark.read().json(anotherPeopleDataset);
anotherPeople.show();
// +---------------+----+
// |        address|name|
// +---------------+----+
// |[Columbus,Ohio]| Yin|
// +---------------+----+
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
private static JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>> rows;
private static final Function f = (Function<Map<String, Object>, Row>) strObjMap -> RowFactory.create(new TreeMap<String, Object>(strObjMap).values().toArray(new Object[0]));
public void test(){
    rows = sc.parallelize(list);
    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rows.map(f);
    Map<String, Object> headMap = list.get(0);
    TreeMap<String, Object> headerMap = new TreeMap<>(headMap);
    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    StructField field;
    for (String key : headerMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key:::"+key);
        Object value = list.get(0).get(key);
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            field = DataTypes.createStructField(key, DataTypes.IntegerType, true);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Double) {
            field = DataTypes.createStructField(key, DataTypes.DoubleType, true);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Date || value instanceof java.util.Date) {
            field = DataTypes.createStructField(key, DataTypes.DateType, true);
        }
        else {
            field = DataTypes.createStructField(key, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        }
            fields.add(field);
    }
    StructType struct = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
    Dataset<Row> data = this.spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, struct);
}
```